# Spring Integration Filter With Exception

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I use SpringIntegration-filter for validate my WS message. I implement Validators for validating and if WS message is valid, they returns true. But if WS messages are invalid, they throws a MyValidationException.

Is there a way for handle this exceptions with usage of SpringIntegration-filter? If I don't return false, filter don't work.

My code example is below. I want to use my validation exceptions in discard flow.

```java
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow incomingRequest() {
    return f -> f
        .<IncomingRequest>filter(message ->
            validatorFactory.validator(message.getName())
                .validate(message),
            filterEndpointSpec -> 
                filterEndpointSpec.discardChannel(discardChannel()))
        .<IncomingRequest>handle((payload, headers) ->
            applicationService.handle(payload));
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow discard() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(discardChannel())
        .log("DISCARD FLOW")
        .get();
}

@Bean(name = "discard.input")
public MessageChannel discardChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.direct().get();
}
```

Comment: There are 2 reply from Jose and Gary. They are correct. But In Jose's solution, I must call validator 2 times. Because of that, Gary's solution is more appropriate for me. Thanks Gary and Jose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discard channel just gets the rejected inbound message; there is no way to alter it in the filter.

You can do something like this...

```
.handle()   // return an Exception on validation failure
.filter(...) // filter if payload is exception; the exceptions go to the discard channel
```

i.e. separate the validation and filter concerns.

Comment: Thanks, Can I say that, handle() process is  the standard component for business validation process.

Comment: `.handle()` is a generic processing step - equivalent to a `@ServiceActivator` so, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the exception is comming from the validate when you check the WS request, you have to surround the call in a try catch. If an exception is thrown, it is catched and `false` is returned, indicating that the validation failed.

```java
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow incomingRequest2() {
    return f -> f
            .filter(this::isValid, filterEndpointSpec -> 
                    filterEndpointSpec.discardFlow(f2 -> f2.transform(this::getReason))
                            .discardChannel(discardChannel()))
            .<IncomingRequest>handle((payload, headers) ->
                    applicationService.handle(payload));
}
```

And the helper methods.

```java
public boolean isValid(IncomingRequest message) {
    try {
        return validatorFactory.validator(message.getName())
                .validate(message);
    } catch (Exception e) { // your exception
        return false;
    }
}

public String getReason(IncomingRequest message) { // return the object you need
    try {
        validatorFactory.validator(message.getName())
                .validate(message);
        return null;
    } catch (Exception e) { // process exception as you want
        return e.getMessage(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. In this state, if I catch this exception and return false, can I reached my thrown exception as payload in discard flow? If not, my exception is lost. I want to reach this exception in discard flow.

Comment: I try this solution and I lose my thrown exception in discard flow. Because of that, I cannot use exception info in discard flow.

Comment: I don't think you can get the reason/exception after, maybe if you re-evaluate the validator in another flow would work.

Comment: Separate the concerns (validation and filter) rather than trying to do both. See my answer.

Comment: That's a way two, i just don't like to use instanceof in the filter, and i normally use a function to check if something is valid and another to get why, the overhead is insignificant.